# How should I go about Devise user registration from an Android form?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm currently working on an Android application that is interfacing with a Rails application.  This Rails application is using Devise for user authentication.

Right now I'm stuck on how to allow user registration from the Android side of things.  I've got an Android view/form that is sending key/value pairs to the Rails application (username, password, email), but I'm unsure how to handle things from there.

I want to register a user without rendering any HTML.  I just want a response to the Android application that either has a success message or gives me the validation errors.

My first thoughts were to create my own registration controller that would have access to the POST data from the Android registration form, and using this data I would interact with Devise.  And then my registration controller would send back some response (maybe XML?).

Does anyone have any advice on how I can go about this?

Comment: I am no rails expert, but it sounds like you need a standard webservice, which will take in the users details, process them, and then send a response back to the app. Its a standard HTTP response you need, and you can get this information from the Android client from the execute() method in the HTTP classes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

The two major things I did were customizing a Devise route and creating a custom registration controller.

Here is the route:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Then, this is what the custom registration controller looks like:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

  def create

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { super }

      format.xml  { 

        build_resource

        if resource.save

          # custom code....

          render :status => 200, :xml => "<XmlResponse />"

        else

          # handle invalidation...

          render :status => 207, :xml => "<XmlResponse />"

        end

      }

    end

  end

end
```